# Draw cross inside circle using patches in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

How can I draw an X inside the outer circle (top left) in the plot below using `Patches`? I do not want to plot a data point since the axes limits can change (I'm plotting this inside another figure), or when I tried using `text` the font looks strange. I have this

```
f = plt.figure(figsize=(6, 6))
ax = f.add_subplot(111)

box = ax.get_position()
axColor = plt.axes([box.x0 + 0.05, box.y0 + 0.05,
                    0.6, 0.6], projection='polar')

axColor.set_yticks([])
axColor.set_xticks([])
axColor.set_rlim(0, 50)

circle = plt.Circle((0., 0.), 10, transform=axColor.transData._b,
                   edgecolor='k', facecolor='None', linewidth=2)
axColor.add_artist(circle)
circle = plt.Circle((0., 0.), 3, transform=axColor.transData._b, 
                   color='k', linewidth=2)
axColor.add_artist(circle)

circle = plt.Circle((-0.02, 0.9), 0.1, transform=axColor.transAxes,
                   edgecolor='k', facecolor='None', linewidth=2, clip_on=False)
axColor.add_artist(circle)
# Cannot draw an X
```

And the image is

[image]

Comment: image error...
Firefox has detected that the server is redirecting the request for this address in a way that will never complete.
Chrome: i.stack.imgur.com redirected you too many time.

Comment: I do not quite understand why you need two axes here, but did you try using a `\times` symbol? `ax.text(-0.02, 0.9, "$\times$", ha="center", va="center", transform=ax.transAxes)`

Comment: Yes I tried, but text does not position nicely as the Circle patch does, it slightly shifts. Also, if you rescale the figure size you have to manually increase/decrease the font size. I need the figure inside another axis because I'm using the polar axis as a circular colorbar (using pcolormesh)

Answer (score 2):

Simple and quick way to draw an x on the plot of yours could be to use plt.scatter. You can make use of the x marker to put the x in the center of the circle you have. Check the following code, it draws the x in the center of the leftmost circle. The coordinates you need to provide for the marker are the same relative coordinates you pass to create the circle.

```html
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

f = plt.figure(figsize=(6, 6))
ax = f.add_subplot(111)

box = ax.get_position()
axColor = plt.axes([box.x0 + 0.05, box.y0 + 0.05,
                    0.6, 0.6], projection='polar')

axColor.set_yticks([])
axColor.set_xticks([])
axColor.set_rlim(0, 50)

circle = plt.Circle((0., 0.), 10, transform=axColor.transData._b,
                   edgecolor='k', facecolor='None', linewidth=2)
axColor.add_artist(circle)
circle = plt.Circle((0., 0.), 3, transform=axColor.transData._b, 
                   color='k', linewidth=2)
axColor.add_artist(circle)

circle = plt.Circle((-0.02, 0.9), 0.1, transform=axColor.transAxes,
                   edgecolor='k', facecolor='None', linewidth=2, clip_on=False)

axColor.add_artist(circle)


mymarker = plt.scatter(-0.02, 0.9, s=300, c='red', transform=axColor.transAxes, marker='x', clip_on=False)
axColor.add_artist(mymarker)



f.savefig('plot_with_x.png')
```

I also attached the image here. You can adjust the size of the marker by adjusting the value of s and change the color with c.
Hope this helps.

[image: Image with x on the circle]

Comment: Thanks, this helps. However if I reduce the figure size I have to rescale the marker size manually. It's different with the circle since it will always have a fixed radius. I'll wait if someone have a different answer

Comment: I see. In that case, I guess you can adjust the size based on the radius of the circle. The change in the size of the marker should be linear to the change in the parameter s. Maybe you could set the marker as some_coefficient*radius_circle.